# Me falla un código completamente válido en los punteros _begin y _end

Tags: c++

No entiendo por qué este código falla en tiempo de ejecución, compila sin errores y por mucho que reviso el código no veo por qué debería saltar un `segmentation fault`:

```
#include <iostream>

constexpr std::size_t BUFF_SIZE { 256u };

int buffer[BUFF_SIZE] {};
int *_begin = buffer;
int *_end   = buffer + (BUFF_SIZE / 2u);

int main()
{
    for (unsigned indice{}; indice < (BUFF_SIZE / 2u); ++indice) {
        *(_begin + indice) = indice;
        *(_end + indice)   = (BUFF_SIZE / 2u) - indice;
    }

    for (const auto &v : buffer) std::cout << v << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Puede verse el código funcionando [[aquí]](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/cRYRP9sx8c9MqmbX).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Problema.

El problema es que `_begin` y `_end` no son nombres aconsejables para utilizar en variables.

Los nombres que empiezan con guión bajo (`_`), pese a no ser [palabras clave](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword) del lenguaje C++ están reservados para ser usados por los compiladores, así que usarlos puede interferir con su funcionamiento.

#### ¿Qué ha pasado?.

Por ejemplo, el compilador `gcc` (usado en el código que falla) [declara los símbolos `_etext`, `_edata` y **`_end`**](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/end.3.html) (la traducción y es mía):

> ```
> DESCRIPCIÓN
>        La dirección de estos símbolos indica el final de varios segmentos
>        del programa:
>
>        etext  Esta es la primera dirección tras el final del segmento de
>               texto (el código del programa).
>
>        edata  Esta es la primera dirección pasado el final del segmento
>               datos inicializados.
>
>        end    Esta es la primera dirección pasado el final del segmento
>               de datos no inicializados (también conocido como segmento
>               BSS).
>
> NOTAS
>        En algunos sistemas los nombres de estos símbolos son precedidos
>        por guiones bajos, esto es: _etext, _edata y _end. Estos símbolos
>        también son definidos por programas compilados en Linux.
> ```

Seguramente el símbolo `_end` del compilador ha [ocultado](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) la variable `_end` y se ha intentado modificar una dirección de memoria a la que no deberíamos tener acceso, dando lugar al `segmentation fault`.

#### Detalles técnicos.

El [estándar de C++](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) indica que los compiladores pueden usar variables que empiecen por guión bajo (`_`) a su conveniencia:

En la sección **`§2.10`** (la traducción y el resaltado son míos):

> #### 2.10 Identificadores
>
> ...
>
> 3. Adicionalmente, algunos identificadores están reservados para las implementaciones de C++ y no deben ser usados para otros fines; **no se requiere ningún diagnóstico**.
>
>    3.1. — Cada identificador que contenga un doble guión bajo `__` o empiece por un guión bajo seguido de una letra en mayúscula **está reservado para cualquier uso que requiera la implementación**.
>
>    3.2. — Cada identificador que empiece por un guión bajo **está reservado para ser usado por la implementación como nombre en el espacio de nombres global**.

El propio estándar indica que *no se requiere ningún diagnóstico* en caso de que un identificador considerado como reservado sea usado en el código. Esto significa que a diferencia de las palabras clave que emiten un error de compilación si son usadas como identificadores los identificadores reservados no emiten error ni alarma de compilador al ser usados en el código.

#### Solución.

No uses el guión bajo (`_`) para nombrar variables o macros:

```
#include <iostream>

constexpr std::size_t BUFF_SIZE { 256u };

int buffer[BUFF_SIZE] {};
int *begin = buffer;
int *end   = buffer + (BUFF_SIZE / 2u);

int main()
{
    for (unsigned indice{}; indice < (BUFF_SIZE / 2u); ++indice) {
        *(begin + indice) = indice;
        *(end + indice)   = (BUFF_SIZE / 2u) - indice;
    }

    for (const auto &v : buffer) std::cout << v << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

El código anterior imprime:

> ```
> 0
> 1
> 2
> 3
> 4
> 5
> 6
> 7
> 8
> 9
> 10
> 11
> 12
> 13
> 14
> 15
> 16
> 17
> 18
> 19
> 20
> 21
> 22
> 23
> 24
> 25
> 26
> 27
> 28
> 29
> 30
> 31
> 32
> 33
> 34
> 35
> 36
> 37
> 38
> 39
> 40
> 41
> 42
> 43
> 44
> 45
> 46
> 47
> 48
> 49
> 50
> 51
> 52
> 53
> 54
> 55
> 56
> 57
> 58
> 59
> 60
> 61
> 62
> 63
> 64
> 65
> 66
> 67
> 68
> 69
> 70
> 71
> 72
> 73
> 74
> 75
> 76
> 77
> 78
> 79
> 80
> 81
> 82
> 83
> 84
> 85
> 86
> 87
> 88
> 89
> 90
> 91
> 92
> 93
> 94
> 95
> 96
> 97
> 98
> 99
> 100
> 101
> 102
> 103
> 104
> 105
> 106
> 107
> 108
> 109
> 110
> 111
> 112
> 113
> 114
> 115
> 116
> 117
> 118
> 119
> 120
> 121
> 122
> 123
> 124
> 125
> 126
> 127
> 128
> 127
> 126
> 125
> 124
> 123
> 122
> 121
> 120
> 119
> 118
> 117
> 116
> 115
> 114
> 113
> 112
> 111
> 110
> 109
> 108
> 107
> 106
> 105
> 104
> 103
> 102
> 101
> 100
> 99
> 98
> 97
> 96
> 95
> 94
> 93
> 92
> 91
> 90
> 89
> 88
> 87
> 86
> 85
> 84
> 83
> 82
> 81
> 80
> 79
> 78
> 77
> 76
> 75
> 74
> 73
> 72
> 71
> 70
> 69
> 68
> 67
> 66
> 65
> 64
> 63
> 62
> 61
> 60
> 59
> 58
> 57
> 56
> 55
> 54
> 53
> 52
> 51
> 50
> 49
> 48
> 47
> 46
> 45
> 44
> 43
> 42
> 41
> 40
> 39
> 38
> 37
> 36
> 35
> 34
> 33
> 32
> 31
> 30
> 29
> 28
> 27
> 26
> 25
> 24
> 23
> 22
> 21
> 20
> 19
> 18
> 17
> 16
> 15
> 14
> 13
> 12
> 11
> 10
> 9
> 8
> 7
> 6
> 5
> 4
> 3
> 2
> 1
> ```

Comment: Yo consideraría: 3.2. — Cada identificador que empiece con un guión bajo queda reservado para la implementación, para ser usado como un nombre en el espacio de nombres global.

Comment: @asdasdasd correcto. Hice mal la traducción... *falta de cafeína*.