# error: type 'PrimeraClase' does not provide a call operator

Tags: c++, clase, operador

Estoy tratando de pasar por parámetro un objeto pero me sale un error que no he proveído una llamado al objeto.

Yo quiero usar la segunda definición del constructor por eso la paso como parámetro para poder ingresar las variables por defecto.

Este es mi código:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class PrimeraClase
{
    int valor;
    string nombres;
public:
    PrimeraClase():valor(0),nombres("Por favor ingrese un nombre\n")
    {cout << nombres << "y " "edad: " << valor << endl;}
    PrimeraClase(int _valor, string _nombres):valor(_valor),nombres(_nombres)
    {cout << "su Nombre es: " << nombres << endl <<
            "y su edad es: " << valor << endl;}
};

void preguntar(PrimeraClase &Objeto1)
{
    int num = 24;
    string nom = "Sergio";

    Objeto1(num,nom);
}

int main()
{
    PrimeraClase Objeto1;
    cout << "Mi nombre es sergio\n";
    preguntar(Objeto1);

    return 0;
}
```

Y este es el error que me sale cuando compilo.

```
eje05.cpp:22:2: error: type 'PrimeraClase' does not provide a
      call operator
        Objeto1(num,nom);
```

Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema ocurre en tu codigo, se encuentra en esta funcion:

```
void preguntar(PrimeraClase &Objeto1)
{
        int num = 24;
        string nom = "Sergio";

        Objeto1(num,nom); <-- Sobretodo en esta linea
}
```

En esta linea lo que intentas hacer es llamar al `Objeto1`, como si esta fuera una funcion `Objeto1(num, nom)`, es por ello que te arroja dicho error.

> error: type 'PrimeraClase' does not provide a call operator

Que quiere decir esto?

Al realizar la llamada de `Objeto1(num, nom)` estas llamandolo como si este fuera funcion, es decir usando el *operador()*, pero como no se encuentra ningun operador de llamada *(como ya te lo explica @eferion)* no se puede realizar dicha operacion.

#### Solucion

Existen variadas soluciones, como puedes apreciar, puedes inicializar el objeto de tipo `PrimeraClase` y retornarlo. *(Basado en la respuesta de PaperBirdMaster)*, esto nos permitira que la instanciacion del objeto y el paso de los parametros al constructor se realicen en la misma linea y asi retornaremos al objeto ya inicializado.

```
PrimeraClase preguntar()
{
    int num = 24;
    string nom = "Sergio";

    // Llamada a constructor, no a operador de llamada.
    // Posiblemente se aplique RVO ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization )
    return PrimeraClase(num,nom);
}
```

---

Otra posible solucion a tu inconveniente, seria la que te propongo a continuacion:

Al tener el parametro `Objeto1` el cual es de tipo `PrimeraClase` lo que podemos hacer es *re-inicializarlo*, que quiere decir que, podemos hacer las veces de una declaracion y como usas el operador `&` el cual nos pasa por referencia dicho objeto, puedes volver a inicializarlo, pasandole alli los parametros del constructor.

```
void preguntar(PrimeraClase &Objeto1)
{
        int num = 24;
        string nom = "Sergio";

        Objeto1 = PrimeraClase(num,nom); <--- Llamamos nuevamente al constructor de PrimeraClase
}
```

Lo que dejaria a tu codigo asi:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class PrimeraClase
{

private:
   int valor;
   string nombres;

public:
   PrimeraClase();
   PrimeraClase(int _valor, string _nombres);

};

PrimeraClase::PrimeraClase() : valor(0),nombres("Por favor ingrese un nombre\n")
{
        cout << nombres << "y " "edad: " << valor << endl;
}

PrimeraClase::PrimeraClase(int _valor, string _nombres) : valor(_valor),nombres(_nombres)
{
        cout << "su Nombre es: " << nombres << endl <<
                "y su edad es: " << valor << endl;
}

void preguntar(PrimeraClase &Objeto1)
{
        int num = 24;
        string nom = "Sergio";

        Objeto1 = PrimeraClase(num, nom);
}


int main()
{
        PrimeraClase Objeto1;
        cout << "Mi nombre es sergio\n";
        preguntar(Objeto1);

        return 0;
}
```

**Resultado:**

```
Por favor ingrese un nombre
y edad: 0
Mi nombre es sergio
su Nombre es: Sergio
y su edad es: 24
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por su respuesta, pero me hizo surgir otra pregunta. ¿Entonces yo siempre tendré que re-inicializar mi objeto cada vez que lo envié como parámetro o es que mi código o es que esto pasa solo por que lo declare en el main y luego lo paso como parámetro y lo vuelvo a inicializar con nuevos valores?

Comment: No, no, no. El compilador **NO interpreta** como si existiese una clase llamada `Objeto1` e intenta llamar al constructor, el compilador **SABE** que existe una instancia de `PrimeraClase` e intenta llamar al operador paréntesis.

Comment: Por favor, corrige los errores de tu pregunta para que no cause confusión en futuros lectores

Comment: Que la respuesta que has dado solucione el problema no implica que la base sobre la que te apoyas lo sea. Como bien te ha comentado @PaperBirdMaster el compilador no interpreta nada... o encuentra algo o no lo encuentra. En este caso el compilador trata de buscar el operador función para un objeto de tipo `PrimeraClase` (de echo puedes hacer la prueba y crear una clase de nombre `Objeto1` con el constructor adecuado y el error que recibirás al compilar será exactamente el mismo que el comentado en la pregunta).

Comment: Luego insisto, tu respuesta es incorrecta porque la justificación que das para el error no es para nada correcta y es por eso que te pido que soluciones ese punto. La idea es no confundir a futuros lectores

Answer (score 2):

> error: type 'PrimeraClase' does not provide a call operator

Mediante este error el compilador te está indicando que el tipo `PrimeraClase` no dispone de operador de llamada (*does not provide a call operator*).

#### ¿Qué es el operador de llamada?

Cuando una clase sobrecarga [el operador paréntesis](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Function_call_operator) (`operator ()`) se transforma en un [funtor](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funtor). Es decir, pasa a ser un objeto que puede llamarse como si fuera una función. Podemos verlo en este ejemplo:

```
struct funtor
{
    /* Operador de llamada que recibe un entero con signo, las
    instancias de funtor podran ser llamadas como si fuesen una
    funcion que recibe un numero */
    void operator()(int numero) { std::cout << numero << '\n'; }

    /* Operador de llamada que recibe una cadena de texto, las
    instancias de funtor podran ser llamadas como si fuesen una
    funcion que recibe un texto */
    void operator()(std::string texto) { std::cout << texto << '\n'; }
};

struct clase_normal
{
};

funtor a, b;
clase_normal c, d;

a(42);          // Llama a funtor::operator()(int), muestra '42'.
b("Abubilla!"); // Llama a funtor::operator()(std::string), muestra 'Abubilla!'.
a(b);           // error: no existe funtor::operator()(funtor &);
b(c);           // error: no existe funtor::operator()(clase_normal &);

c(42); // error: el tipo 'clase_normal' no provee un operador de llamada
d(42); // error: type 'clase_normal' does not provide a call operator
```

#### ¿Por qué recibes este error?

Estás confundiendo [instancias](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instancia_(inform%C3%A1tica)) con [tipos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tipo_de_dato) en la función `preguntar`:

```
void preguntar(PrimeraClase &Objeto1)
{
    int num = 24;
    string nom = "Sergio";

    Objeto1(num,nom);
}
```

Esta función recibe una **instancia** de **tipo** `PrimeraClase`; dicha **instancia** se llama `Objeto1`. En la última línea de la función `preguntar` usas el operador de llamada con parámetros `int` y `string` sobre la **instancia** `Objeto1` y dado que el **tipo** `PrimeraClase` no proporciona un operador de llamada que reciba `int` y `string`, recibes el error.

Seguramente has creído que estabas llamando al constructor de `PrimeraClase` pasándole los parámetros correspondientes a `_valor` y `_nombres`, pero no es así, la instancia que pasas a `preguntar` ha sido construida (con el constructor sin parámetros) en `main` y acto seguido pasada a la función `preguntar` como instancia.

#### ¿Qué hacer?

Deduzco que quieres que la función `preguntar` pregunte al usuario unos datos y después construya una instancia de `PrimeraClase` con los datos obtenidos; de ser así tienes las siguientes opciones:

**Devolver objeto construido en la función**.

```
PrimeraClase preguntar()
{
    int num = 24;
    string nom = "Sergio";

    // Llamada a constructor, no a operador de llamada.
    // Posiblemente se aplique RVO ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization )
    return PrimeraClase(num,nom);
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Mi nombre es sergio\n";
    // Obtiene el objeto construido dentro de la funcion preguntar
    PrimeraClase Objeto1 = preguntar();

    return 0;
}
```

Esta solución crea el objeto dentro de la función `preguntar` y devuelve el objeto ya construido. En compiladores de C++ modernos el objeto es construido una sola vez, pero si estás compilando con compiladores antiguos o con opciones de optimización bajas cabe la posibilidad de que se hagan dos construcciones del objeto y una copia.

**Funciones de establecimiento y consulta de valores**.

Si quieres trabajar sobre objetos ya construidos a los que les vas a modificar los valores que contienen, necesitarás funciones de establecimiento y consulta de valores:

```
class PrimeraClase
{
    int valor;
    string nombres;
public:
    PrimeraClase() :
        valor(0),
        nombres("Por favor ingrese un nombre\n")
    {
        cout << nombres << "y edad: " << valor << endl;
    }

    PrimeraClase(int _valor, string _nombres) :
        valor(_valor),
        nombres(_nombres)
    {
        cout << "su Nombre es: " << nombres << endl << "y su edad es: " << valor << endl;
    }

    void EstablecerValor(int _valor) { valor = _valor; }
    void EstablecerNombres(int _nombres) { nombres = _nombres; }
};
```

Teniendo estas funciones que establecen los valores de la clase, la función `preguntar` quedaría así:

```
void preguntar(PrimeraClase &Objeto1)
{
    int num = 24;
    string nom = "Sergio";

    Objeto1.EstablecerValor(num);
    Objeto1.EstablecerNombres(nom);
}

int main()
{
    PrimeraClase Objeto1;
    cout << "Mi nombre es sergio\n";
    preguntar(Objeto1);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Otras cosas a tener en cuenta.

- [Evita usar identificadores que empiecen con guion bajo (`_`)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/24544/2742).
- La instrucción `cout << nombres << "y " "edad: " << valor << endl` funciona porque los literales de cadena anexos se concatenan durante la fase de compilación, pero seguramente lo has escrito así por error.

Answer (score 1):

> Estoy tratando de pasar por parámetro un objeto pero me sale un error que no he proveído una llamado al objeto.

Veamos el código:

```
void preguntar(PrimeraClase &Objeto1)
{
    int num = 24;
    string nom = "Sergio";

    Objeto1(num,nom); // <<--- AQUI
}
```

La instrucción que te destaco con el comentario está intentando llamar al operador función del objeto `Objeto1`. Dicho objeto no posee un operador función válido y de ahí el error.

No creo que de momento necesites saber lo que es el operador función, así que me saltaré esa parte. El caso es que el compilador no es capaz de encontrar un operador función válido y por eso aborta el proceso y te muestra un error.

> Yo quiero usar la segunda definición del constructor por eso la paso como parámetro para poder ingresar las variables por defecto.

Si lo que quieres es modificar el objeto a partir del segundo constructor debes tener en cuenta que los constructores únicamente son llamados al crear nuevos objetos, luego la mecánica a seguir sería crear un nuevo objeto y después realizar una asignación:

```
void preguntar(PrimeraClase &Objeto1)
{
    int num = 24;
    string nom = "Sergio";

    Objeto1 = PrimeraClase(num,nom);
}
```

Habría otras posibilidades, como habilitar funciones para modificar los valores miembro sin necesidad de recurrir a estos artificios:

```
class PrimeraClase
{
    int valor;
    string nombres;
public:

    PrimeraClase();
    PrimeraClase(int _valor, string _nombres);

    // Funciones individuales
    void SetValor(int valor)
    { this->valor = valor; }

    void SetNombres(const std::string& nombres)
    { this->nombres = nombres; }

    // Todo en uno
    void SetValores(int valor, const std::string& nombres)
    {
      this->valor = valor;
      this->nombres = nombres;
    }
};

void preguntar(PrimeraClase &Objeto1)
{
    int num = 24;
    string nom = "Sergio";

    // opcion 1
    Objeto1.SetValor(num);
    Objeto1.SetNombres(nom);

    // opcion 2
    Objeto1.SetValores(num,nom);
}
```